Output Variable stays unintialised in my VHDL testbench
I am pretty new to VHDL and was trying to write a VHDL simulation for a simple master-slave toggle flip flop.
Following is the VHDL code that I have written:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity TFF is
    Port(
            t : in std_logic;
            clk : in std_logic;
            q : out std_logic;
            qBar : out std_logic
        );
end TFF;

architecture Behavioral of TFF is
    
   signal q1,q1bar, q2, q2bar : std_logic ;
begin 
    
    --MASTER
    q1 <= not(q2bar and t and clk) nand q1bar;
    q1bar <= not(q1 and t and clk) nand q1;
    
    --SLAVE
    q2 <= (q1 nand clk) nand q2bar;
    q2bar <= (q1bar nand clk) nand q2;
    
    q <= q2;
    qBar <= q2bar;
    
end Behavioral;

And following is the testbench that I have written:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity tff_tb is
end tff_tb;

architecture Behavioral of tff_tb is

component TFF is
    Port(
            t : in std_logic;
            clk : in std_logic;
            q : out std_logic;
            qBar : out std_logic
        );
end component;

signal t_tb : std_logic;
signal q_tb : std_logic ;  
signal qBar_tb : std_logic ; 
signal clk_tb : std_logic := '0';
constant clk_period : time := 100 ns ; -- 100MHz

begin
    
    -- CLOCK
    clk_tb <= not clk_tb after clk_period/2;
        
    --instantiate UUT
    TFF_map : TFF port map
            (
                t   => t_tb,
                clk  => clk_tb,
                q    => q_tb,
                qBar => qBar_tb
            );
    stimulus : process begin
        
        t_tb <= '0'; wait for  100 ns;
        t_tb <= '1'; wait for  100 ns;
        t_tb <= '0'; wait for  100 ns;
        t_tb <= '1'; wait for 300 ns;
        --wait for 200ns;
        wait;
    end process;
    
end Behavioral;

I don't get any errors in my simulation, but q and qBar continue remaining uninitialised throughout the simulation. I was expecting the two ports to stay uninitialised for the first few clock cycles instead.
What is it exactly that I am doing wrong?

There's another alternative, providing a reset or clear to the TFF:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity TFF is
    port (
            t : in std_logic;
            clk : in std_logic;
            clr:    in  std_logic;  -- CHANGED ADDED
            q : out std_logic;
            qBar : out std_logic
        );
end TFF;

architecture masterslave of tff is
    alias j is t;
    alias k is t;
    signal clkn:    std_logic;
    signal mg:      std_logic;
    signal mg_n:    std_logic;
    signal mq:      std_logic;
    signal mq_n:    std_logic;
    signal sg:      std_logic;
    signal sg_n:    std_logic;
    signal sq:      std_logic;
    signal sq_n:    std_logic;
begin

INV_CLK:
    clkn <= not clk;

NANDMG:
    mg   <= not (sq_n  and clkn and j);
NANDMGN:
    mg_n <= not (sq    and clkn and k);

NANDMQ:
    mq   <= not (mg   and mq_n);
NANDMQN:
    mq_n <= not (mg_n and not clr and mq);
    
NANDSG:
    sg   <= not (mq   and clk);
NANDSGN:
    sg_n <= not (mq_n and clk);
    
NANDSQ:
    sq   <= not (sg   and sq_n); 
NANDSQN:
    sq_n <= not (sg_n and sq);

    q <= sq; 
    qbar <= sq_n;

end architecture;

This is from a model of a JK flip flop. The J and K inputs are both tied to the toggle enable input, here by aliases to leave the JK model readily visible.

architecture Behavioral of tff_tb is

component TFF is
    port (
            t : in std_logic;
            clk : in std_logic; 
            clr:    in  std_logic;    -- CHANGED ADDED
            q : out std_logic;
            qBar : out std_logic
        );
end component;

signal t_tb : std_logic;
signal q_tb : std_logic ;  
signal qBar_tb : std_logic ; 
signal clk_tb : std_logic := '0';
    signal clr_tb:  std_logic;
constant clk_period : time := 100 ns ; -- 100MHz

begin
    
    -- CLOCK
    -- clk_tb <= not clk_tb after clk_period/2; -- CHANGED self stopping model
    clk_tb <= not clk_tb after clk_period/2 when now < 1 us;
        
    --instantiate UUT
    TFF_map : TFF port map
            (
                t   => t_tb,
                clk  => clk_tb,
                clr  => clr_tb,   --- CHANGED ADDED
                q    => q_tb,
                qBar => qBar_tb
            );
    stimulus : process begin
        t_tb <= '0'; wait for  100 ns;
        t_tb <= '1'; wait for  100 ns;
        t_tb <= '0'; wait for  100 ns;
        t_tb <= '1'; wait for 300 ns;
        --wait for 200ns;
        wait;
    end process;
    
RESET:   -- CHANGED ADDED
    process
    begin
        clr_tb <= '1';
        wait for 30 ns;
        clr_tb <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;
    
end Behavioral;


and that produces:

where you have a signal for every NAND gate output. Note this uses the falling edge of clock for the master unlike Matthias' answer which might necessitate relabeling the clock signal.
You can also get rid of the unknown values on the slave/Q and slave/QN outputs before the first rising edge of the clock by adding another term:
NANDSQN:
    sq_n <= not (sg_n and not clr and sq);

to clear the slave stage while clr is '1'.

Thanks, this works :) Just out of curiosity, what does 'g' stand for in mg/mgn and sg/sgn?

g stands for gate. It makes a bit of sense if you do something old school and draw out a schematic. Somewhere I have a jpeg of logic gates showint clr and pre.

Right, makes sense. I did manage to make a schematic out of your well written VHDL code.
I have one more question. I had previously written a VHDL script and testbench for a simple D-Flip Flop but I hadn't used a 'clear' port to initialise 'q' and 'q_bar'. I did not face any issues in the simulation. 'q' and 'q_bar' remained uninitialised ('u') for only sometime and then they started working just like how it is happening in your code. Is there a particular reason for that? How will I know when to use 'clear' to initialise my variables?

Add a term to the last NAND gate as indicated at the bottom of the answer sq_n <= not (sg_n and not clr and sq);. Where you can see the clr term is added NANDSQN. It will clear the slave latch as well as the master. I had left it as is because you appeared to be expecting some unitialized values, then added the bit at the bottom of the answer.

@toolic is right, nobody will try to model a flipflop with your style in a productive design.
But of course if you only want to learn VHDL you can do that.
But there are several problems in your design.
First as @toolic said, the combinatorial feedback causes problems. But only because your design has 3 bugs.
To identify these bugs I introduced delays for the assignments to q1, q1bar, q2, q2bar.
After fixing I removed the delays and everything worked fine.
These are the problems:

There is a typo: Instead of q1bar <= not(q1 and t and clk) nand q1; it must be q1bar <= not(q2 and t and clk);.
In a master/slave combination when the master is transparent, then the slave stores and vice versa. This means, one of them must get the original clock signal and the other must get the inverted clock signal.
I inverted the clock signal for q2/q2bar to keep changes as small as possible.
Each storing device must be initialized at simulation start.
When you do not initialize, then the value of the storing signal is 'U' and if you try to toggle this value, it cannot switch to 0 or 1.
You can initialize by a hardware reset signal or you can initialize q1, q1bar, q2, q2bar at declaration (my solution).

The working code is this:
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity tff is
    port (
        clk  : in  std_logic;
        t    : in  std_logic;
        q    : out std_logic;
        qbar : out std_logic
    );
end entity tff;
architecture struct of tff is
    signal q1    : std_logic := '0';
    signal q1bar : std_logic := '1';
    signal q2    : std_logic := '0';
    signal q2bar : std_logic := '1';
begin
        --MASTER
        q1    <= not(q2bar and t and clk) nand q1bar;
        q1bar <= not(q2    and t and clk) nand q1   ;
        --SLAVE
        q2    <=     (q1    nand not clk) nand q2bar;
        q2bar <=     (q1bar nand not clk) nand q2   ;
    
        q    <= q2;
        qBar <= q2bar;
end architecture;


This works :) It's just that I am not a huge fan of initialising the variables as I believe it strays away from what happens in real world. But then, I can understand that the very idea of coding a sequential logic using a combinatorial construct isn't the best way out like you and @toolic have mentioned.

The problem is that you are trying to use combinational feedback to model sequential logic.  You should use the appropriate code style to model a flip-flop.  For example, refer to D-type flip-flops on Wikipedia:
DFF : process(all) is
begin
  if RST then
    Q <= '0';
  elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
    Q <= D;
  end if;
end process DFF;

You can adapt that style for your TFF design logic.

I have a question. According to what I can sense, this type of code style works for problems which are simple in nature like the T Flip Flop or the D Flip Flop, where the truth table is small enough. How does such kind of coding construction work for very complicated circuits where there might be tons of gates and a giant truth table? I feel that such scenarios can be difficult to decode into if and else / case statements.

@Rohan: It's very simple.  It all depends on whether you logic is combinational or sequential.
